# Android: CustomListView click on image of the row

Tags: android, custom-lists

I have a custom list view which have a TextView and an image.
What I want to do is when I click on the image, an event happen.
And if I click on the TextView, nothing happen.

Can I handle it in Activity class?

Please help me to overcome this problem.
 I search too much, but I can't find out what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just find the Views in your activity and set listeners, rather than using an onItemClickListener (or Overriding on OnLIstItemClick())?

Comment: but TextView and ImageView belong to the Custom Adapter and not available in Activity

Comment: Oh. Can't you use an xml file to define a list item?

Comment: see the Line user clearly said 
_I have a custom list view which have a TextView and an image_ in the question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store a copy of the activities context from the adapter's constructor which can then be used in the getView override to set the ImageView's click handler to the activites onClick member function.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity 
{   
    public void onClick(final View v)
    {
        // handle click event
    }

    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<string>
    {
        private Context mContext;
        private List<string> lineItems;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<string> lineItems)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, lineItems)

            mContext = context;
            this.lineItems = lineItems;
        }

        @Override
        public View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

                v = li.Inflate(R.Layout.list_item_layout, null);
            }

            Imageiew imageView = (ImageView)v.FindViewById(R.Id.image_view_id);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(mContext.onClick);

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```